# Why not all labels are showing in matplotlib legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize feature embeddings of dataset with 20 classes in a 2-d space using t-sne method, but my matplotlib legend is missing most of the labels. It should show all the labels in y but only showing first 7 labels. What I am missing here?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
tsne_model = TSNE(n_iter=2000, n_components=2, random_state=123, perplexity=50)
tsne_transformed = tsne_model.fit_transform(pca_result_50)

sns.set_style('white')
f = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = plt.subplot(aspect='equal')
sc = plt.scatter(tsne_transformed[:, 0], tsne_transformed[:, 1], c=labels, cmap='tab20')
handles, _ = sc.legend_elements(prop='colors')

y = ['0 - Original', '1 - Original', '2 - Original', '3 - Original', '4 - Original', '5 - Original', 
'6 - Original', '7 - Original', '8 - Original', '9 - Original','0 - Generated', '1 - Generated', 
'2 - Generated', '3 - Generated', '4 - Generated', '5 - Generated', 
'6 - Generated', '7 - Generated', '8 - Generated', '9 - Generated']

plt.legend(handles, y, loc='best')

plt.xlabel('t-sne 1')
plt.ylabel('t-sne 2')

plt.xlim(-25, 25)
plt.ylim(-25, 25)
ax.axis('tight')
```

Comment: DId you try to change legend size? For example: `plot.legend(prop={'size': 6})`
Sometimes is because of this.

Comment: @Enrique it is only affecting the size of the legend, not the number of labels inside it.

Comment: Did you try `sc.legend_elements(prop='colors', num=20)`? Or `sc.legend_elements(prop='colors', num=None)`? [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.legend_elements)

Comment: @JohanC Thank you. It worked with ```sc.legend_elements(prop='colors', num=20)```